# Eglot and MS SQL

Tags: eglot, sql

I was looking for a way to use Eglot with the MSSQL Server. I found this GitHub repo https://github.com/emacs-lsp/lsp-mssql, but this is for lsp-mode and not for Eglot.

Is there an Eglot configuration/repo for the MSSQL Server?